# Are automorphism groups of semistable sheaves reductive?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question is in the title. I am interested in characterisitic zero cases.

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $\Bbbk$ and $L$ an ample line bundle. Then we can define Gieseker stability for coherent sheaves. I know that for geometrically stable sheaves, the automorphism group is $\Bbbk^\times$. I now wonder what about Aut of a semistable sheaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily reductive. For instance, if $X$ is an elliptic curve and $E$ is defined as a non-trivial extension
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to E \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0
$$
then $\mathrm{Hom}(E,E) \cong \Bbbk[t]/t^2$, where $t$ is the composition
$$
E \to \mathcal{O}_X \to E.
$$
Consequently, $\mathrm{Aut}(E)$ is an extension of $\mathbb{G}_m$ by $\mathbb{G}_a$.